# Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-gesture-handler`

Tags: react-native

*I try to use  navigate in react-native.. 
I added :* `npm install --save react-navigation`

but it gives me an error like this :

*error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-gesture-handler` from `C:\reactnative\proejectName\node_modules\@react-navigation\native\src\Scrollables.js`: Module `react-native-gesture-handler` does not exist in the Haste module map*

**this is index :**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

**This is app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, } from 'react-navigation';
import First from './src/Components/First';
import DescriptionPage from './src/Components/DescriptionPage';


const Navigation = createStackNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: First,
  },
  DescriptionPage: {
    screen: DescriptionPage,
  },
});

const App = createAppContainer(Navigation);

export default App;
```

**this is package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.1",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.10",
    "react-navigation": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.2",
    "babel-jest": "24.5.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: what does your `package.json` looks like ?

Comment: In order to use react navigation you have to install react-native-gesture-handler too: [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You need to install `react-native-gesture-handler` as well separately in the project dependency list and link it too with native as well. Please refer to this [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installation).

Comment: @MaykedaRosaHerbst If you look at the `gesture-handler` library, then you will get to know why the `react-navigation` devs have gone with it to keep the navigation transitions smooth and performant.

Comment: When I try to install, getting error "npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git"

Comment: i have some issue with sqlite, i create the insert fetch delete functions and for some  reason it doesn't work for me. can you help me please ?

Comment: that doc doesn't mention installing `react-native-gesture-handler`

Comment: For those that already have "react-native-gesture-handler" installed and use more modern versions of react-native, I suggest to take a read in the official documentation ["Testing with Jest"](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/guides/testing), which states to add `"setupFiles": ["./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"]` in jest config within package.json. This configuration adds RNGH's mocks into jest.

Answer (score 35):

Use the following command to install

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
```

Then link the library in the specific project

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Comment: The [`docs`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installation) say linking is only needed for react native v0.59 and below

Comment: This should be the answer. The 'answered' one does not mention this neither does the docs that were linked. Thank you.

Answer (score 27):

Gesture Handler not found in your react native project. run this command

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler
```

Comment: Complementando: ```npm i react-native-gesture-handler --save && react-native link```

Comment: Yeah need to add the link bit for this one!

Answer (score 8):

This error occurs for two main reasons.

- If you didn't install `react-native-gesture-handler`, then npm or `yarn add react-native-gesture-handler`.
- If you already did, then you need to rebuild your app, for android `react-native run-android` and for ios you should install pods then run again.

  `cd ios && pod install --repo-update && cd .. react-native run-ios`

you may need to restart metro again, `react-native start`.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue. Solved it by:

```
npm uninstall react-native-gesture-handler --save

npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case `react-native-gesture-handler` was installed but I uninstalled it and re-installed again.

1: uninstall

```
npm uninstall react-native-gesture-handler --save
```

2:  install

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save
```

3: link

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

4: Restart npm

```
npm restart
```

or

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 6):

If you already have install...

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler
```

Make a `import 'react-native-gesture-handler'` On the first line of your App.js code (Attention must be on the first line, on top of all your code and any import)

Just uninstall your application running on your emulator or any physical device and run again (install again) and it will work..

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using expo, you have to install it through expo command:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler
```

Answer (score 3):

For newcomers here:

1. If you are using expo, you can simply run the following command to install the appropriate version for your react native version

```
react-native-gesture-handler
```

2. Note that `createStackNavigator` has been moved to  `react-navigation-stack`, so the right import  becomes :

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
```

Comment: Usually from the corresponding official github repos and their release notes : https://github.com/react-navigation/stack/releases

Answer (score 2):

If you have started your application before installing dependencies, you might need to reinstall the application again on your phone or emulator. That was the case for me.

After installing dependencies [as shown in the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation#react-navigation), I needed to:

1. Remove the application from emulator
2. Run `yarn android` (or  `npm run android`) again through terminal

**NOTE:** I am **NOT** using [Expo](https://expo.io/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading to SDK 39.

Run This Command :

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be as simple as forgetting to wrap your code in app.js after installing the gesture handler package as seen from your code given in the package documentation. Don't forget the flex value else you'll get a blank screen. I had the same issue

```
<GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>
  //your code goes in here
</GestureHandlerRootView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your react-navigation version 3.11.0.

[image]

And then `npm install react-native-gesture-handler` command

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running mac please do the following:

1. Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm install --save react-navigation`
4. `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`
5. `cd ios`
6. `pod install`

Then run again

Comment: use in android !!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case, installation of the react-native-gesture-handler itself was failing. I was using react-native version 0.61.5. Due to some reasons latest version of the react-native-gesture-handler was not getting installed with my project. I solved the error by installing specific version of the react-native-gesture-handler.

```
   npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler@1.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following commands to install

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
```

For React Native versions < v 59.x, link the library in the specific project

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's working**

```
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
```

**use this instead of**

```
"react-native-gesture-handler": "1.8.0",
```

**remove ^**

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have this issue where even after installing the npm package it will still throw errors. You could try adding the following line to the top level component/file of your app e.g. `index.js`

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by:

1. Running `npx react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`
2. Uninstalling the debug application from the device
3. Running `npx react-native run-android`

Comment: shouldn't need to manually link anymore, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
```

Or with npm if you prefer:

```
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
```

Reference from https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/

Answer (score 0):

For me, and this is a weird one. I had the `react-native start` terminal window already open and running the metro bundler for ***another/different RN app*** already running. After I killed it, and re-ran `yarn ios`, and it reopened its own metro bundler window -my error was gone

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-navigation v6, you don't need `react-native-gesture-handler` you can just remove it, with

```
npm uninstall react-native-gesture-handler
```

mind you, its with only version 6 that you're free to remove it

Comment: In my case, it did not work. When I uninstall it, it throwed me this error. "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_ReanimatedModule.default.createNode')
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error after installation of react-native-gesture-handler because
your react-native version is less than react-native: "60" so after installation
you have to link that module "react-native link react-native-gesture-handler".
And build again it will resolve your error

Answer (score 0):

**Note: If you don't use [Eas build](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id0Im72UN6w&t=670s) in your app. This comment is not for you.**

I will share my case and How I solved it.

**Stack**
I am using.

- Expo
- react-native-firebase, native library.
- [Eas build](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id0Im72UN6w&t=670s), to process the native library inside Expo.

**Problem**

I followed all the steps that library said.

npm install:

- @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
- @react-navigation/drawer
- @react-navigation/native
- @react-navigation/native-stack
- react-native-reanimated
- react-native-safe-area-context
- react-native-screens
- react-native-gesture-handler

> import "react-native-gesture-handler"; // First line of my project

However, it didn't work.

**Solution**

Brother, it was really simple. But it took me a lot of time to discover. I just had to rebuild the **EAS BUILD** with the command.

`eas build --profile development --platform android`

download the build on my phone and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I manual enter the `"react-native-gesture-handler":"2.9.0"` in package.json and run `yarn add`.
finally Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made the same mistake as me:

I added the wrong library.

I should use

```
import {FlatList, View} from 'react-native';
```

instead of

```
import {FlatList} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using `registerComponent` to register a custom Android Custom Activity. I solved it by wrapping it in `gestureHandlerRootHOC`.

```
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('prompt', () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(Prompt));
```