# react-native-gesture-handler module was not found, even though its clearly installed

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am trying to install [@gorhom/bottom-sheet](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/) in my react-native bare project.  I have followed the instructions there, which include the instructions for installing `react-native-gesture-handler` and `react-native-reanimated`.  After installing `react-native-gesture-handler` and running my app, I see this error message in the iOS simulator (iphone 14):

> react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked properly (cd ios && pod install && cd ..)

As per the instructions, I have run `npm install react-native-gesture-handler`, as well as put the import in my root index.js file:

```js
// index.js

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

I have also run `pod install` in the `/ios` folder.  Still, I am seeing this error.  I have tried:

- Following the instructions at https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/installation/
- Deleting and reinstalling all node_modules, as well as ios/Pods
- Cleaning my build folder via xcode
- Running `npx react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`, which tells me that `link` is an unknown command (no longer part of the react-native cli for my version, which is 0.71.8)

My issue is not the same as the question [Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-gesture-handler`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55358811/error-unable-to-resolve-module-react-native-gesture-handler), as in that question, the issue was attempting to install `react-navigation` without manually installing `react-native-gesture-handler`.   The solution in the question [react-native-gesture-handler module was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096484/react-native-gesture-handler-module-was-not-found) is also not helpful, as the issue there was that the poster had changed the app name and the config file could no longer be found, and used `react-native link` with an older version of react-native to discover the issue.

I am at a loss here. It seems I have installed the module correctly and the code can very much be found in my node_modules folder.  I need this dependency for both `@gorham/bottomsheet` as well as `react-navigation`.  What am I doing wrong?

Versions:

```
  "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.6",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.71.8",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.10.2",
```

Comment: @BalaVigness, No, I literally wrote in my question how *that* question does *not* solve my problem, and why it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Could you upload your code to the GitHub repository?